# Cannot find module 'jquery' when using browserify

Tags: jquery, npm, browserify

I am trying to use browserify for a small web application, what I would like to
achieve is pretty basic: I would like to be able to `require('jquery')` in
my JS code instead of having the dependency linked with a `<script>` tag in
the HTML code.

So, I have this in the first line of my JS file called `main.js`:

```
require('jquery');
```

Then, I start browserify to produce `bundle.js`:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Output:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'jquery' from /home/matias/dev/app/js
```

However, it seems jquery is properly installed:

```
npm -g list | grep jquery
```

returns `jquery@2.1.4`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

*EDIT*: installing modules 'locally' (without -g option) seems to work with browserify - is it the right way to do ? I would prefer to have it using globally installed modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is highly recommended to install modules locally. This way, each project depends on the specific versions it needs, and there is no risk of regressions from backwards-incompatible changes. When you upgrade a global module, anything that depends on it could potentially break.

Whether you are using browserify or not, npm dependencies should be fixed to a specific version (likely, the latest version at the time of authoring). They should only be upgraded (past a major version) when you have the time to test and make sure nothing breaks, using a tool such as [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates).

*All that said*, you can run [`npm link jquery`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) from inside your project directory to make the local dependencies (in node_modules) symlink to the globally installed jquery. This is helpful when you are developing the dependency module, but it is not suitable for normal use.

In your situation, use local dependencies.