# Ember cli - Cannot find module 'jquery' when importing NPM package using ember-browserify

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I have installed the jscrollpane node module:

```js
$npm install --save-dev jscrollpane
```

I have also installed ember-browserify, so that I can import npm modules into my ember components, as per [this article](http://www.jimmylauzau.com/blog/2016/03/22/importing-node-modules-in-ember-js).

I import the module into my component:

```js
import Jscrollpane from 'npm:jscrollpane';
```

The module is found, but I get this error:

**Error: Cannot find module 'jquery' from '/Users/username/my-app/node_modules/jscrollpane/script'**

I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676438/cannot-find-module-jquery-when-using-browserify) which suggests adding jQuery to the relevant npm module (In this case **my-app/node_modules/jscrollpane/script.**).

It seems undesirable to add an additional copy of jQuery to a node module directory- is there a better way of making node modules aware of where to find the core Ember cli version of it?

Answer (score 0):

I think jScrollPane is attempting to resolve a copy of jQuery loaded via AMD (https://github.com/aibarra988/jScrollPane/blob/master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js#L68-L73). ember-cli uses a custom resolver which does not have jQuery exposed in the global scope. ember.js includes jQuery by default under `Ember.$`.
quick ideas on solutions:

1. write some kind of shim that exposes `Ember.$` to `jquery` as jScrollPane expects by default
2. find jScrollPane packaged for bower and import it within `ember-cli-build.js` (not "the best" but it works)
3. embed a modified version of the file within `vendor` directory and import it using `ember-cli-build.js`. e.g. `app.import('vendor/js/something.jquery.js');`
   If you want to do this the "right way", I suggest asking around in slack: https://embercommunity.slack.com/messages/-ember-cli/

Answer (score 0):

I have since found [Ember Perfect Scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-perfect-scrollbar) which does the same thing as jScrollpane, but works perfectly with Ember.